# Version One - Open and Close Story with API

Tags: versionone

Does anyone know if it is possible to open and/or close VersionOne Stories via their API?

A major kink in our process is that a story has to be open in order to modify it.  In order to solve this I was hoping to delve into their API (which seems to have very poor documentation).  I'm able to update stories with just the API, but run into the same issue of not being able to update a story if it has already been closed.  Is there a way (via the API) that I can open the ticket, make my change, and then re-close it?  Or can that only be done through their web UI ?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring this out, you can append an 'op' to the url of a body-less POST request to 'reactivate' and 'quickclose' stories

Example URLs:

```
/api/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect/<id>?op=Reactivate
```

to reopen a closed story

and

```
/api/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect/<id>?op=QuickClose
```

to close a story